# use of typedef struct in embedded C code

Tags: c, syntax, typedef

I came across this piece of code in one of MicroChip's example codes. I'm unable to understand what it exactly means

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed))
{
    BYTE command;
    BYTE data;
} ACCESSORY_APP_PACKET;
```

I can understand that a struct aliased ACCESSORY_APP_PACKET is being created, but what does the `__attribute__((packed))` mean? It makes `__attribute__` as a function. But if that is so, how is it being typedef'd as a struct?

BYTE is a known datatype made by Microchip.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not part of the typedef, nor is it a function.  It's a compiler extension using syntax that sort of looks "function-like" perhaps.  It is used to change the way the struct members are packed in memory so it uses minimal space, rather than being packed in a potentially larger way that might execute faster.

Answer (score 3):

`__attribute__` is a `gcc` compiler option that specifies a separate behavior of the compiler on compilation.

In your case it says to the compiler not to use padding between structure members.

Comment: so as far as I am concerned, the code simply means a struct alias ACCESSORY_APP_PACKET was created with 2 BYTE elements in it?

what does "not to use padding between structure members" exactly mean?

Comment: Is it related to the fact that if i create a struct with say 2 booleans, the whole things becomes 2 bytes long instead of 2 bits long?

Comment: @AdwaitDongare in order to make structure members access faster, structure members are padded to a processors word size (`char` member takes e.g `4` bytes instead of `1`byte). Thus in your case you're forcing the structure to have size `2` bytes instead of `8` (this value can be dependent on the compiler/platform etc).

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a function. It's an attribute (this is a GNU extension). It specifies that there should be no padding between the members of the struct (which otherwise there can be).